# Configuring the Linux Kernel(menuconfig): redifinition errors

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel

I have the Linux Kernel 3.8.0 source code and when attempting to configure it using the **menuconfig** option(using the "make menuconfig" terminal command), I get the following list of errors:

```
DALEK linux-3.8.0 # make menuconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/mconf.o
In file included from scripts/kconfig/expr.h:15:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/lkc.h:9,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:22:
scripts/kconfig/list.h:23:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct list_head’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/signal.h:9:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:18:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/linux/list.h:19:8: note: originally defined here
In file included from scripts/kconfig/expr.h:15:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/lkc.h:9,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:22:
scripts/kconfig/list.h:57:19: error: conflicting types for ‘list_empty’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/signal.h:9:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:18:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/linux/list.h:193:19: note: previous definition of ‘list_empty’ was here
In file included from scripts/kconfig/expr.h:15:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/lkc.h:9,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:22:
scripts/kconfig/list.h:68:20: error: conflicting types for ‘__list_add’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/signal.h:9:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:18:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/linux/list.h:44:20: note: previous definition of ‘__list_add’ was here
In file included from scripts/kconfig/expr.h:15:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/lkc.h:9,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:22:
scripts/kconfig/list.h:86:20: error: conflicting types for ‘list_add_tail’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/signal.h:9:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:18:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/linux/list.h:81:20: note: previous definition of ‘list_add_tail’ was here
In file included from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:23:0:
scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/dialog.h:62:0: warning: "MIN" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/ctype.h:27:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:11:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/features.h:153:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:23:0:
scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/dialog.h:63:0: warning: "MAX" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/ctype.h:27:0,
                 from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:11:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/features.h:148:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/mconf.o] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
DALEK linux-3.8.0 #
```

So apparently the source code in the /scripts/kconfig/ use the linux headers by the Kernel source code defines data structures and constants that are previously defined in the headers. What should I do to correct this so I can run menuconfig?

Comment: Where did you get this Linux source from?

Comment: I downloaded it [Here]https://www.kernel.org/

Comment: May I know for which arch and which board you want compile this kernel?

Comment: I am building this custom kernel for Linux Mint 15(kernel version 3.8.0-19-generic).

Comment: My machine has a motherboard with INTEL x86_64 architecture.

Comment: make arch=x86_64 menuconfig,did you try this?

Comment: I haven't but I will give it a go and see if that works.

Comment: Amit Singh Tomar, I did try that and I __STILL__ got a list of compiler errors that are related to redefinitions. That is what seems to be the problem with configuring the Kernel. However, the **make defconfig** works.

Answer (score 0):

So I modified the linux kernel code in the /scripts/kconfig folder to clean out the redefinitions and use the headers with the original defs and now the Menuconfig works just fine.